# Libre Office Calc List every wednesday

Tags: worksheet-function, libreoffice, libreoffice-calc

I'm trying to list the date every Wednesday in a column for a budget sheet. I think I need the DATE function, but I don't know how to find the "day" value of Wednesdays in an arbitrary month.

Comment: Use WEEKDAY function.

Answer (score 1):

Welcome!

The first Wednesday for the specified Year and Month is found using the formula

`=DATE(Year;Month;1)+MOD(4-WEEKDAY(DATE(Year;Month;1));7)`

[**Add 7,14,21 to get the 2nd, 3rd, 4th Xday of some month**](https://forum.openoffice.org/en/forum/viewtopic.php?t=73070)